# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, ngfor

Estoy intentado iterar un array que contiene objetos, este array si itera en la consola pero no en la vista, lanzandome este error:

> core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

---

Vista de angular en la que no se puede iterar (me lanza el error):

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let candidate of candidatesPresidential'>
     <div>{{candidate['Distrito Electoral']}}</div> //no itera
</ng-container>
```

---

Los datos que quiero iterar provienen de un servicio y son traídos mediante el *ngOnInit*:

```
import { CandidatesPresidentialService } from '../../../core/services/canditates-presidential.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'list-candidates',
    templateUrl: './list-candidates.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list-candidates.component.css'],
    providers: [CandidatesPresidentialService],
})
export class ListCandidatesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    candidatesPresidential: Array<any>;

    constructor(
        private _candidatesPresidentialService: CandidatesPresidentialService,

    ) { }
    getMessageFromFrontComponent() {

        //traigo el array de mi servicio
        this.candidatesPresidential = this._candidatesPresidentialService.getCandidatesPresidential();

        //itera correctamente en la consola
        this.candidatesPresidential.forEach((element) => {
            console.log(element['Distrito Electoral']);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getMessageFromFrontComponent();
    }
}
```

---

El servicio debe retornar un array bastante simple:

```
@Injectable()
export class CandidatesPresidentialService {

    listCandidatePresidential: Array<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.listCandidatePresidential = [
            {
                'Distrito Electoral': 'NACION',
                'Organización Política': 'ACCION POPULAR',
                'Tipo Organización Política': 'PARTIDO POLÍTICO',
                'Cargo': 'PRESIDENTE DE LA REPUBLICA',
                'N°': '1',
                'Primer apellido': 'BARNECHEA',
                'Segundo apellido': 'GARCIA',
                'Prenombres': 'ISAAC ALFREDO',
                Sexo: 'Masculino',
            },
            {
                'Distrito Electoral': 'NACION',
                'Organización Política': 'ACCION POPULAR',
                'Tipo Organización Política': 'PARTIDO POLÍTICO',
                'Cargo': 'PRIMER VICEPRESIDENTE DE LA REPUBLICA',
                'N°': '2',
                'Primer apellido': 'GARCIA',
                'Segundo apellido': 'BELAUNDE',
                Prenombres: 'VICTOR ANDRES',
                Sexo: 'Masculino',
            }
         ]
     }

    getCandidatesPresidential() {
        return this.listCandidatePresidential;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmmm, es extraño intente replicar tu error pero me corre todo bien

Comment: Tal vez podrías intentar ver como llega el array en el HTML, poniendo algo así como `<section>{{candidatesPresidential | json}}</section>`, para ver con que tipo de estructura se encuentra, esa porción de código la pones antes o después de tu `ng-container`

Answer (score 0):

Te sale este error porque no incializas la variable `candidatesPresidential: Array<any>;` con un valor por defecto. Cuando el `*ngFor` intenta iterar esta variable aun será `undefined` y por eso sale este error.

Con esto debería solucionarse

```
candidatesPresidential: Array<any> = [];
```

O puedes poner otro `ng-container` con un `ngIf` para comprobar que `candidatesPresidential` tenga valor.

No puedes poner el `ngIf` en el mismo `ng-container` que el `ngFor`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf='candidatesPresidential && candidatesPresidential.length'>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let candidate of candidatesPresidential'>
     <div>{{candidate['Distrito Electoral']}}</div> //no itera
  </ng-container>
<ng-container *ngFor='let candidate of candidatesPresidential'>
```